# pass session variable into asp:gridview's sqldatasource select command

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I am currently having trouble trying to get a select command with a session variable in my asp gridview. I have been looking on here and other sites and have not really came across much. It's got to be a simple fix that i just have not came across yet. Here is my code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:mySql_Connection %>"
                    SelectCommand =  "Select [Username], [Name] FROM UserPassword WHERE CustID = '" & session("CustID") & "'>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm not even sure if that is close to correct or not. I get `the server tag is not well formed`. Or invalid syntax. Can someone show how to do this. I've been stuck on this and its really bugging me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Session Paramter

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:mySql_Connection %>"
                SelectCommand =  "Select [Username], [Name] FROM UserPassword WHERE CustID     = @CustID>
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:SessionParameter Name="CustID" SessionField="CustID"
   DefaultValue="0" />

 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can refer the below link also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx

Comment: so what would i do sessionParameter Name = "CustID" SessionField = "CustID"? and would the select command be FROM UserPassword WHERE CustID = CustID">?

Comment: made some edits.. in the command give your parameter name starting with with '@'. I do so usually on code behind, but the example in MSDN article given has just a '?'

Comment: see i tried that before and got this same thing "Must declare the scalar variable "@CustID"."

Comment: can you try just a '?' as given in the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx

Comment: Or this can help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/03/03/must-declare-the-scalar-variable.aspx

Comment: lol now i get this as well .Incorrect syntax near '?'. '<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mySql_Connection %>"
                        SelectCommand =  "Select [Username], [Name] FROM UserPassword WHERE CustID = ?">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="CustID" SessionField="CustID"
                    DefaultValue="0" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource' That is my code. hmm....

Comment: i am not sure why this happens, is there a specific reason you do not want to do this in code behind

Comment: mainly because im not 100% sure how to